# Autocomplete controls in XForms

Tags: autocomplete, xforms, orbeon

Can anyone please give me an idea on how to autocomplete input controls in XForms such that when a user begins typing words that begin that way appear?

Also how can I populate a control from the value of another control? Like in a drop down menu when a user selects a country name, the next field is automatically populated with that country's capital.

Country: Egypt
City: Cairo                 (City should appear automatically)

Answer (score 2):

XForms itself does not provide autocomplete functionality, but Orbeon Forms implements such a control with XBL and JavaScript. [Here is the documentation](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xbl-components/autocomplete).

The control has multiple modes, but you typically use it  this way:

```
<fr:autocomplete ref="country-name" dynamic-itemset="false">
    <xforms:label>Enter a country name: </xforms:label>
    <xforms:itemset nodeset="instance('all-countries')/country">
        <xforms:label ref="name"/>
        <xforms:value ref="name"/>
    </xforms:itemset>
</fr:autocomplete>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the autocomplete idea, too bad am not developing in Orbeon. Could i just use <fr:autocomplete> in my coding then i include its namespace? Will it work, because am writing the actual codes myself (not using any GUI application).

Comment: @System_me, if you're not using Orbeon Forms, but another XForms engine, you cannot use the `<fr:autocomplete>` control, which is Orbeon-specific. However, the XForms implementation you're using might have a similar feature. Since the answer to this question will be implementation-specific, I would suggest you edit your question to include that name of that implementation in the question, maybe even the title.